# Bootstrap - Preventing Navbar from vertical stacking on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the below Bootstrap 3 code, the nav bar will wrap vertically when in an iPhone. How do I prevent the vertical stacking. I wish it to stay horizontal on the bottom in one line.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ny Title</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li> 123 </li>
      <li> 123 </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That will cause other navbars on your page to not be responsive too though. You should add a custom class name to the navbar and target the above properties to that.